# Erro de aninhamento

Tags: r, ggplot2

Preciso fazer um gráfico no R concatenado, são 4177 iterações, estou usando o ggplot2, mas tá  dando o erro abaixo:

```
Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?

#geradora de dados sintéticos (triangulos)
#argumentos: numero de poligonos desejados, numero de vertices
gera_poligonos = function(numero_objetos, numero_vertices){
  dados = NULL
  for(i in 1:numero_objetos) dados[[i]] = matrix(rnorm(numero_vertices*2), ncol = 2)
  return(dados)
}  
#Funcao que plota os poligonos desejados (neste caso triangulos)
plot_poligono <- function(poligono){
  numero_vertices = nrow(poligono[[1]])
  g = ggplot()
   if(numero_vertices == 3){
    for(i in 1:length(poligono)){
       g = g + geom_polygon(data = data.frame(poligono[i]), aes(x = X1, y =      X2), colour="black", fill = NA)
    }
    return(g)
 }
  else print("Insira um poligono de tres vertices")    
}

#
teste = gera_poligonos(4177, 3)
plot_poligonos(teste)
```

Comment: Corrija seus erros de ortografia, arrume e organize seu texto, poste o código (nem que seja inteiro) pela aba "code" e coloque em esconder código, vai ajudar sua pergunta a ser respondida e evitar down votes.

Comment: Wagner, esse erro é muito genérico, é impossível dar qualquer sugestão sem ver o código. No mínimo você deveria postar a linha que dá o erro, mas mesmo assim será difícil entender o problema. Investigue o seu código e busque reduzir a um exemplo mínimo reprodutível, com menos dados, menos manipulação, etc, mas que gere o erro. Caso contrário acho que não conseguiremos te ajudar.

Comment: Editei, coloquei o código mais simples que pude, julguei ser um erro específico. Obrigado pessoal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma, ao invés de ir adicionando camadas ao seu gráfico. O parâmetro `group` no `ggplot` faz com que seja construido um gráfico p/ cada grupo, sem a necessidade de você ir adicionando camadas ao gráfico.

```
teste = gera_poligonos(4177, 3)
names(teste) = 1:length(teste)
k <- plyr::ldply(teste, function(x) data.frame(x))
g <- ggplot(k, aes(x = X1, y = X2, group = .id)) + geom_polygon(colour = "black", fill = NA)
g
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]